# What are some practical and potential applications of Galois theory in different field of mathematics?

Tags: galois-theory, book-recommendation

Apart from providing solution to classical questions like

*Solvability of quintic or higher degree polynomial equations in terms of radicals*

Also, any related book recommendation, guys？

Comment: Number theory, especially algebraic number theory and arithmetic geometry use Galois theory.

Comment: Galois theory can be restated using category theory, so you might be [interested in taking a look at this](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1078&context=rhumj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Galois theory is a general phenomenon, that shows up in the context of [Category Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection), [Mathematical Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780612/model-theoretic-galois-correspondence), [Differential Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory), [Algebraic Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670807/applications-of-galois-theory-for-topology) and [Algebraic Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35503/a-galois-group-is-a-fundamental-group). Here is a summary of two most relevant examples of Galois theory itself, from number theory and algebraic geometry separately.

- [Class Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory): Given a number field $K$, its [class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) $Cl(K)$ measures how much its integer ring $\mathcal O_K$ fails to have unique factorization property. This purely intrinsic group is isomorphic to a Galois group $G(L|K)$ where $L$ is a certain abelian extension of $K$, that is called the [Hilbert class field](https://kskedlaya.org/cft/sec_hilbert.html) of $K$. This is just the starting point of Galois theory being an essential part of modern algebraic number theory.
- [Weil's Conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures): The rational points on an algebraic variety can be viewed as those that are invariant under Galois action of $G(\overline{K}|K)$. When the base field is a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, the Galois group is essentially generated by the Frobenius map. To count the fixed points of the map, one can [invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_trace_formula) ideas of counting [fixed points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem) in topology.